# Missing \endcsname inserted. \newlabel{comparison 75\%}{{1}{1}}, i am getting this error while compiling table

Tags: tables, captions

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{multicol}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\begin{document}
    
    \onecolumn
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \caption{Eigenvalues of Study System with and without SSSC for 75\% hybrid series compensation}
        \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}
            \toprule
            \multirow{4}{*}{Mode}&\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{75\% Compensation level}\\
            \cmidrule{2-5}
            &\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{case:1(without SSSC)} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{case:2(with SSSC)} \\
            \cmidrule{2-5}
            &$\sigma\pm j\omega$& $\zeta$ &$\sigma\pm j\omega$& $\zeta$ \\
            \midrule 
            Super-Synchronous   &-9.5903$\pm$629.17i&0.01524 &-12.344$\pm$556.39i&0.02218\\
            Sub-Synchronous     &1.6034$\pm$123.7   &-0.01296&-9.0587$\pm$137.23i&0.06586\\ 
            Shaft        &-0.4911$\pm$6.1496i&0.07962  &-0.48842$\pm$6.1493i&0.07917\\
            Torsional    &-85.88 $\pm$38.471i&0.91261  &-85.883$\pm$37.936i&0.91474\\
            Electromechanical &-11.602$\pm$91.825i&0.12535  &-9.6224$\pm$94.729i&0.10106\\ 
            \midrule
            \multirow{7}{*}{Other}&-2416.6$\pm$1271.4i&0.88511  &-2421.1$\pm$1252.1i&0.88825\\
            &      0$\pm$0i     &  -      &-2670.3            &1     \\ 
            &   0$\pm$0i        &   -     &-110.25            &1      \\
            &      -0.12579     &    1    &-0.15132           &1      \\
            &     -0.0035219    &   1     &-0.0034435         &1      \\
            &                   &         &0$\pm$0i           &-     \\ 
            &                   &         &0$\pm$0i           &-      \\                  
            \bottomrule
            \label{comparison 75\%}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}   
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \caption{Eigenvalues of Study System with and without SSSC for 90\% hybrid compensation}
        \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}
            \toprule
            \multirow{4}{*}{Mode}&\multicolumn{4}{c}{90\% Compensation level}\\
            \cmidrule{2-5}
            &\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{case:1(without SSSC)} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{case:2(with SSSC)} \\
            \cmidrule{2-5}
            &$\sigma\pm j\omega$& $\zeta$ &$\sigma\pm j\omega$& $\zeta$ \\
            \midrule 
            Super-Syn.   &-10.42$\pm$653.25i  &0.01595 &-13.605$\pm$570.94i &0.02382\\
            Sub-Syn.     &6.3734$\pm$108.15i  &-0.05883&-1.1691$\pm$113.64i &0.01028\\ 
            Shaft        &-0.48923$\pm$6.1509i&0.07928&-0.48455$\pm$6.1504i&0.07854\\
            Torsional    &-86.432$\pm$38.566i &0.91322 &-86.534$\pm$37.766i &0.91652\\
            Electromechanical &-16.399$\pm$82.919  &0.19402 &-19.362$\pm$91.845i &0.20628\\ 
            \midrule
            \multirow{7}{*}{Other}&-2387.2$\pm$1205i   &0.89272 &-2393.8$\pm$1183.5i &0.89642\\
            &    0$\pm$0i        &-       &-2205.5             &1\\ 
            &    0$\pm$0i        &-       &-111.35             &1\\
            &     -0.14669       &1       & -0.18936           &1\\
            &-0.0021773          &1       &-0.0020965          &1\\
            &                    &        &0$\pm$0             &-\\ 
            &                    &        &0$\pm$0             &-\\                  
            \bottomrule
            \label{comparison 90\%}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated to the issue itself, but please keep in mind that horizontal lines from teh `booktabs` package are designed to be used without vertical lines, hence the gaps around the intersections. Please also be aware that your table is currently wider than the textwidth. You might want to adapt that.

Comment: Regarding the `subfigure` package. Please keep in mind that this package is deprecated. Use `subcaption` or `subfig` instead. Please also make sure you only load package once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more minimal example, that still allows to reproduce the error message

```
Missing \endcsname inserted. \%  \newlabel{comparison 75\%}{{1}{1}}
```

is

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \caption{Eigenvalues ...}\label{comparison 75\%}
    \end{table}   
\end{document}
```

The error is caused by the use of `\%` inside of the label. Using something like `\label{comparison75percent}` or `\label{comparison75}` makes the code compilable without error messages.

---

Apart from that, the `\label` is placed at the wrong position. Move it outside of the `tabular` environment but after `\caption`.